# Devtool refuses to display "My uri" in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'DENY'

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

In my Java Spring MVC web application, I use Hibernate, H2, and JPA to store data. I am trying to visualize the data on my database using [devtool](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-devtools/1.3.0.RELEASE). I also use [Spring Security](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-security/1.5.0.RELEASE), to secure my app.

**Unfortunately, I cannot load the page** `http://localhost:8080/h2-console/login.do?jsessionid=bcdfd8af18f9fa24d1874314750585bd` **which is supposed to show my database records.**

It complains in **Chrome** with:

```
Refused to display 'http://localhost:8080/h2-console/query.jsp?jsessionid=bcdfd8af18f9fa24d1874314750585bd' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'DENY'.
```

and in **Firefox** it complains with:

```
Load denied by X-Frame-Options: http://localhost:8080/h2-console/query.jsp?jsessionid=bcdfd8af18f9fa24d1874314750585bd does not permit framing.
```

My configuration of Spring Security is:

```java
@Configuration
static class WebFormsSecurityConfigurerAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .csrf().disable();
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/h2-console/**").permitAll();
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/welcome").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/account/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/account/**").authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login").permitAll()
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/welcome")
                .and()
            .logout().logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"));    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

By default, Spring Security disables rendering within an iframe, see [Spring Security Reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#headers-frame-options):

> **20.1.5 X-Frame-Options**
>
> [...]
>
> A more modern approach to address clickjacking is to use X-Frame-Options header:
>
> ```
> X-Frame-Options: DENY
> ```
>
> The X-Frame-Options response header instructs the browser to prevent any site with this header in the response from being rendered within a frame. By default, Spring Security disables rendering within an iframe.

but you can change the default, see [Spring Security Reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#headers-frame-options):

> Similarly, you can customize frame options to use the same origin within Java Configuration using the following:
>
> ```java
> @EnableWebSecurity
> public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
>
>     @Override
>     protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
>       http
>       // ...
>           .headers()
>               .frameOptions()
>                   .sameOrigin();
>     }
> }
> ```

If you want to use a frame from a different origin, you can disable the [`X-Frame-Options`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7034) HTTP header, see [FrameOptionsConfig#disable](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configurers/HeadersConfigurer.FrameOptionsConfig.html#disable--):

> Prevents the header from being added to the response.